How to enable DCR using Duende Identity Server and RSK AdminUI
I want to use DCR(Dynamic Client Registration) using the Duende Identity Server. I am also using Rocksolid Knowledge's AdminUI to handle Identity Server.
But when I am trying to make an API call to the DCR Endpoint of the Identity Server, it gives me 404.
I have tested the DCR endpoint when I installed the standalone Identity Server using their quickstart guide.
Now I am not sure why RSK's version does not allow DCR.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
